# Why is there a AnonymousIdentifier_AD7E5BED-EF7F-59A7-856F-6984BE798469.plist file in CrashReporter folder?

Tags: macos, logs

I found a file AnonymousIdentifier_AD7E5BED-EF7F-59A7-856F-6984BE798469.plist in my /Library/Application Reporter/CrashReporter folder.

The content of that plist included a dictionary with key AnonHostUUID2 and a long hexadecimal string value.

What would create this file, and why?

Comment: I had one of those as well, and it only contained an AnonHostUUID2 key. I didn't find any files containing that UUID either.

Comment: This is not an attempted hacking against my computer, right?

Comment: @user51665 If you're thinking "Anonymous" here refers to the group, then you're wrong. Apple collects anonymous information whenever something crashes to diagnose and fix problems, if any. This file probably contains that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CrashReporter creates those files for later uploading to Apple's servers. The files contain anonymous information (hence the prefix `AnonymousIdentifier`) about the crashes to help Apple diagnose and fix problems.